Defer loading of .wasm file in Kotlin/Wasm
By default, Kotlin/Wasm generates a module that immediately tries to load the .wasm file at startup.
In my case, this does not work because of the special path behavior.
Is there a way to add a init function in Kotlin/Wasm, like in Wasm-Rust, so that I can initialize it whenever I need?
